# CSS3 transform not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to transform my menu items by rotating them 10 degrees. My CSS works in Firefox but I've failed to replicate the effect in Chrome and Safari. I know IE doesn't support this CSS3 property so that's not a problem.

I used following CSS:

```
li a {
   -webkit-transform:rotate(10deg);
   -moz-transform:rotate(10deg);
   -o-transform:rotate(10deg); 
}
```

Could anybody please suggest where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, IE does support this CSS3 property, you just need a prefix: `-ms-transform:rotate(10deg);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS transform doesn't work on inline elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements)

Comment: Since nobody has mentioned this yet, since it's 2016 now make sure you place the unprefixed version of the CSS rule (e.g. `transform: rotate(10deg);`) underneath whichever prefixed versions you choose to support.

Answer (score 442, accepted):

This is merely an educated guess without seeing the rest of your HTML/CSS:

Have you applied `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to `li a`? If not, try it.

Otherwise, try applying the CSS3 transform rules to `li` instead.

Comment: An explanation would be helpful :)

Comment: Explanation: Inline elements behave like text, while block elements behave like containers. You cannot rotate text characters, but you can rotate their container. See [this](https://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/) and [this](https://www.lifewire.com/block-level-vs-inline-elements-3468615) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html_blocks.asp). *(Did you know <textarea> is an inline element? Whodathunk...?)*

Comment: In my case I was transforming a `::before` on a button, `inline-block` didn't work for me but `flex` did???

Comment: Not just rotate, but this applies to any kind of transform.

Answer (score 71):

In webkit-based browsers(Safari and Chrome), `-webkit-transform` [is ignored on inline elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121843/applying-css-class-with-webkit-transform-does-not-work-in-safari-or-chrome). Set `display: inline-block;` to [make it work](http://phihag.de/2011/so/css3-rotate.html). For demonstration/testing purposes, you may also want to use a negative angle or a `transformation-origin` lest the text is rotated out of the visible area.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, thank you! I used it on <span>&copy</span> to make a copyleft symbol.

Comment: @Elisabeth That's an excellent application. Note that entity references need to be terminated by a semi-colon though (as in `<span>&copy;</span>`), although most browsers render both ways.

Comment: Another note: if you're applying the transform for an interaction state (e.g., `:hover` or `:active`) you'll need to apply the `inline-block` to the element in its default state, e.g., `a { display: inline-block; } a:active { transform: translateY(0.125em); }`. Applying `inline-block` to the interaction state alone doesn't seem to work. In Chrome at least -- it works fine in Firefox.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the fact that `-webkit-transform` doesn't work on inline items. Had been stuck on this previously.

Comment: @phihag Excellent point, you saved me some major hair-pulling! Worth noting that this can cause your elements to disappear after the animation has run.

Answer (score 37):

<sub>Since nobody referenced relevant documentation:</sub>

> [**CSS Transforms Module Level 1 - Terminology - Transformable Element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element)
>
> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a [block-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-level) or [atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13), or whose [display property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption
> - an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or gradientTransform.

In your case, the `<a>` elements are `inline` by default.

Changing the `display` property's value to `inline-block` renders the elements as [atomic inline-level elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13), and therefore the elements become ["transformable"](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element) by definition.

```
li a {
   display: inline-block;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(10deg); 
   transform: rotate(10deg);
}
```

As mentioned above, this only seems to applicable in `-webkit` based browsers since it appears to work in IE/FF regardless.

Answer (score 21):

In my case there was a **CSS animation running on the element** that had a transform that was overriding the transform I was adding to the element.

Comment: This needs more votes! This was exactly my problem. I ended up wrapping the animating element in a container and then applying the transform to the container instead.

Comment: I just added `!important` and it worked so the issue originated from where you mentioned. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifically trying to rotate the links only? Because doing it [on the LI tags](http://jsfiddle.net/B7Rez/) seems to work fine.

[According to Snook](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation) transforms require the elements affected be block. He's also got some code there to make this work for IE using filters, if you care to add it on(though there appears to be some limitation on values).

Answer (score -4):

`-webkit-transform` is no more needed

ms already support rotation ( `-ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);` )

try this:

```
li a {
   ...

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -sand-transform: rotate(10deg);
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    }
```

Comment: During my tests today, I noticed that `-webkit-transform` was indeed no longer needed in Chrome. However, it was still needed in Safari 8.

Comment: What is -sand-transform for? A brief Google search turned up nothing.

Comment: google 'CSS Sandpaper' which is relevant to the question and may make things easier.

it is a hack that implements support for the standard CSS transform for old versions of IE