# transform CSS style has no effect on an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, transform

Disclaimer: There is clearly no good reason for doing this. If you'd like your `<a>` to be "moveable" stick it in a `<div>`.

But I want to know if it is documented anywhere (and if a reason is provided as to why) about this behavior.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rBYuT/

Comment: @RabNawaz not really, more like duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919963/css3-transform-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` is `display: inline` by default.  Translation cannot be applied to inline elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/rBYuT/1/

Apparently this is an error too: http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/PTkCE/

> According to the spec, transform should work on both inline and block elements.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#transform-property