# Is it possible to use the nth-child value as a parameter in a property? (and how)

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-animations

### Short description (tl;dr;)

Is there a "pure CSS" way (not Less/Sass) of using the value of the `nth-child` inside the CSS properties? Something like this:

```
span.anim:nth-child(N) { animation-delay: N * 0.5s; }
```

If there is, how can I do it? If there is not, how could I mimic it in a clean way? (I'm sure that I'm over-complicating things here)

---

### Long description

I was creating a simple animation in which letters fade in while rotating. For that, I was using a combination of javascript (with jQuery) and CSS, but that created some problems (see below); so I tried to move to a CSS-only solution, and that ended in a large amount of rules.

This (simplified) CSS is common to both solutions:

```
span.anim {
    font-size:30px;
    opacity:0;
    animation: anim 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes anim {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

**Using JavaScript + CSS**

My JavaScript code looks like this:

```
var aux = $("#animate").text();
$("#animate").text("");

for (var x = 0; x < aux.length; x++) {
    setTimeout('$("#animate").append("<span class=\'anim\'>' + aux[x] + '</span>")', 500 * x);
}
```

This works great... unless the user moves to a different tab, then the animation messes up, and the result is unexpected. You can see it on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e7b9ygk4/ (run the script, move to a different tab, and go back after a few seconds).

**Using only CSS**

I can achieve the same effect by breaking the element in smaller elements (this is the part I feel I'm over-complicating), and then applying the animation to each element with a different delay:

```
span.anim:nth-child(1) { -webkit-animation-delay:0.5s; }
span.anim:nth-child(2) { -webkit-animation-delay:1.0s; }
span.anim:nth-child(3) { -webkit-animation-delay:1.5s; }
span.anim:nth-child(4) { -webkit-animation-delay:2.0s; }
span.anim:nth-child(5) { -webkit-animation-delay:2.5s; }
span.anim:nth-child(6) { -webkit-animation-delay:3.0s; }
span.anim:nth-child(7) { -webkit-animation-delay:3.5s; }
span.anim:nth-child(8) { -webkit-animation-delay:4.0s; }
span.anim:nth-child(9) { -webkit-animation-delay:4.5s; }
span.anim:nth-child(10) { -webkit-animation-delay:5.0s; }
span.anim:nth-child(11) { -webkit-animation-delay:5.5s; }
span.anim:nth-child(12) { -webkit-animation-delay:6.0s; }
span.anim:nth-child(13) { -webkit-animation-delay:6.5s; }
span.anim:nth-child(14) { -webkit-animation-delay:7.0s; }
span.anim:nth-child(15) { -webkit-animation-delay:7.5s; }
span.anim:nth-child(16) { -webkit-animation-delay:8.0s; }
```

This works great, even if the user moves to a different tab, but it results in a lot of *unnecessary* code (both HTML and CSS, although it could be simplified using JavaScript). You can see it working on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f5my3sm1/.

My gut tells me that this could be achieved using Sass/Less, but I want to know if there is a simple "pure CSS" way of doing this, something that could be achieved (hopefully) with a single rule like:

```
span.anim:nth-child(N) { animation-delay: N * 0.5s; }
```

Comment: Simply...no, there isn't

Comment: I feared so. So am I over-complicating this? or the complicated way is the only way in this case?

Comment: Sass/Less were made to reduce unnecessary written code. But it would result in the same css. Wihtout CSS-Frameworks or JS it is not possible. I would say using JS is the shortest and best maintainable solution.

Comment: As you say, this would be very usefull when the length of the lists you'll be creating may be greatly variable. I wonder if this feature would make it to the css4 spec....

Answer (score 14):

[CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) have [almost universal support on all modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables) and can achieve virtually the same desired effect as [@GreatBlake's answer using `attr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29852869/3942699) plus more. Instead of defining data in a user-defined attribute, you can define it as a *custom property* in the `style` attribute and get the value of those custom properties using the `var()` function:

```css
span.anim {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in-and-rotate 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: calc(var(--n) * 0.5s);
}

@keyframes fade-in-and-rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="anim" style="--n: 0">zero</span>
<span class="anim" style="--n: 1">one</span>
<span class="anim" style="--n: 2">two</span>
<span class="anim" style="--n: 3">three</span>
<span class="anim" style="--n: 4">four</span>
```

This code snippet also sets `span.anim`'s `display` property to `inline-block` for the question's provided rotate animation [to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4920080/923560).

Comment: Good compatibility for immediate use

Answer (score 4):

[There is a *very* experimental CSS function for using attributes as properties for an element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr). Currently it only works on pseudo elements, so you'd have to consider coming up with some kind of clever re-working of your markup in this use case.

You could put the offset in a data-attribute on your markup (or with JS), and then use something like the following:

```css
/* attr(name, units, fallback) */
span.anim {animation-delay: attr(offset, 1) * 0.5s;}
```

```html
<span class="anim" offset="0"></span>
<span class="anim" offset="1"></span>
<span class="anim" offset="2"></span>
<span class="anim" offset="3"></span>
<span class="anim" offset="4"></span>
```

Please keep in mind that this is still a ways off from being widely accepted, and like I mentioned before, the above syntax wouldn't work currently because it would need to use pseudo elements like :after.

At the very least, it's something fun to think about.

Comment: Not only does it only work with pseudo-elements, but it only works with the content property. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769786/css3s-attr-doesnt-work-in-major-browsers/8769922#8769922 for more information on the attr() function.

Comment: Thanks! A very nice answer to my similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40761790/how-to-add-a-progressive-animation-delay-based-on-n-th-position?noredirect=1#comment68749717_40761790

Comment: Regarding `<span offset="..."></span>`: `offset` is not a valid attribute for `span` elements. It's better to use *data attributes* to make this valid HTML5: `<span data-offset="..."></span>`, then `attr(data-offset, 1)`.