# CSS animation-delay based on index of an element

Tags: css, css-calc

Is there a way to set `animation-delay` equal to `i * 1s` where `i` stands for index of the element in a parent element? I mean, in pure CSS (with neither Javascript nor LESS/SASS), maybe with `calc()`.

Comment: no it's not possible

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51601269/9256189) is the closest you can go.

Comment: You can do it in pure CSS but it’s a bit tedious. Just have as many settings of the form: .container  > :nth-child(1) { —n: 1; } .container > :nth-child(2) {—n: 2; } etc as you need.  How do we lobby to get the n in nth-child(n) usable?