# Why I can't scale hyper link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to scale hyper link but I can't.

Here is what I tried.

HTML

```
<div class="bgdf">
    <p>
        <small>Copyright <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></span>  All Right Reserved &nbsp &nbsp| &nbsp &nbsp <a href="www.google.com"> Testing </a></small>
    </p>
</div>
```

I tried this

```
.bgdf a:hover{
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```css
.bgdf a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="bgdf">
  <p>
    <small>Copyright <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></span>  All Right Reserved &nbsp &nbsp| &nbsp &nbsp <a href="www.google.com"> Testing </a></small>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `a` element is inline by default.

> [**CSS Transforms Module Level 1 - Terminology - Transformable Element**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element)
>
> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - an element whose layout is governed by the CSS box model which is either a [block-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-level) or [atomic inline-level element](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#x13), or whose [display property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display) computes to table-row, table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-cell, or table-caption
> - an element in the SVG namespace and not governed by the CSS box model which has the attributes transform, ‘patternTransform‘ or gradientTransform.

[Transformations don't apply to strictly `inline` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919963/css3-transform-not-working/28664701#28664701). You could change the `display` of the anchor element to `inline-block` and it should work as expected.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/6vLw72ms/)

```
.bgdf a {
    display: inline-block;
}
.bgdf a:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```